# Multi language CMS?

Tags: content-management-system, multilingual

Is there any CMS such as expression engine or wordpress that allows a user to click a button and convert all the text to another language (it would have to be human generated otherwise it has too many mistakes probably).

I'd like to know if there are any good solutions out there that work for real world use, in like business company websites.

Answer (score 3):

Tridion CMS is designed to assist in website translation.  They even have translation services to help you through the process of translating your content.  It is not a cheap solution but is a viable solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would recoomend you to use Kentico CMS.

See the video on Multilingual support in Kentico CMS:
http://devnet.kentico.com/Blogs/Martin-Hejtmanek/March-2010/Webinar-5---Multilingual-support-in-Kentico-CMS.aspx

Kentico CMS offers multilingual functionality including Right-to-Left languages and Eastern languages. Please see some "live" examples:

Site in 10 languages (incl. Chinese) : http://www.chep.com
Site in 7 languages (incl. Japan, Korean): http://www.wayoutback.com
Arabic: http://www.scb.gov.sa/
Hebrew: http://www.medicsfile.co.il/
Chinese: http://www.royalcaribbean-asia.com/?lang=zh-CN
Hindi site:  http://www.rajasthantourism.gov.in/

More details on multiple languages support:
http://www.kentico.com/cms-asp-net-features/Content-management/Multiple-languages.aspx

Kentico also offers Translation Management:
http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/index.html?translation_management_overview.htm

Especially the translation status overview makes it really easy to manage multilingual web sites. If only a part of web site is translated then you can set to combine the rest with the original language without adding the missing pages in it manually.

Answer (score 2):

As noted above - this is a huge topic and not easily answered briefly. But here are some things to consider...

NO CMS on the market today elegantly interoperates, out of the box, with translation technology for use in real-world translation projects. Reports from clients we've worked with have even raised concerns about the SDL integration.

At best - a handful of CMS's either offer very light-weight features that "appear" to help (side-by-side editing that prevents use of TM) but don't scale or have modest oem connectors to captive translation providers (CQ5<>TDC).

If your needs are modest - these might work fine.

But if you're serious about localization and have a moderate to high volume of content and want to work with any translation provider - you need a proper, rich, scalable integration between your CMS and the TMS (translation management system) used by your Translation firm (LSP).

Regrettably - these are scarce. We do nothing BUT build these connectors and use a neutral platform to provide direct integration all sorts of translation providers and technologies, the full SDL suite included - and still we've only been able to build a few rich CMS plug-in connectors because they are very complicated and require substantial development effort - IF they are going to be useful.

But the CMS choice you make should be driven as much by your broader needs. Localization should only be one facet of the decision process.

I guess the harsh reality is that there is NO CMS that will do what you descibe without smoe modification or a connector.

RK

Answer (score 1):

By default Hippo CMS utilizes Google Translate, but you can plugin your own translation engine / review process. See for more information: http://www.cmswire.com/cms/web-cms/hippo-cms-75-launched-introduces-drag-drop-layout-localization-channel-management-010391.php/

Answer (score 1):

If your organization already uses SDL for translation services then using SDL Tridion is a natural choice because of the built-in connector to send Tridion content for translation using a right-click on the GUI item.  After translation, it is updated in the CMS and the author is notified.

SDL Bought Tridion a few years ago and has been maturing this solution since then.  Today it is available in the current release, Tridion 2011 SP1, and is compatible with both World Server and Translation Management Server.

This is all human translation and any solution that honestly recommends machine translation for final content is not serious about it.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 8 is the best option available for Multilingual capability... Although you have to wait a little bit for its release, You will get a good result. Also earlier versions of drupal including Drupal 7 supports multilingual functionality.

But  Drupal 8 will have more features...With Drupal 8 multilingual functionality, it is possible to translate anything in the system.

The multilingual functionality provides language configuration, assignment and detection functionality. It also provides a user interface to the existing back-end support for automatic software translation. Now it’s more easier to translate contents with the build-in user interfaces.

Plz refer the link for more detailed info  [Drupal 8- What’s new and Expected Inside](http://valuebound.com/blog/drupal-8-what%E2%80%99s-new-and-expected-inside)

Answer (score 0):

Day Communique (CQ5 - now ADEP), in combination with a third-party translation vendor, can do this job.

In Communique/ADEP, you manage your pages in whatever native language you choose. Once they are done, you kick off a translations workflow. This will go to your translation vendor (of which there are several). The vendor will have a human translate it, and possibly also use software to speed up the translation process. It will come back to you for approval in the workflow, if you wish. Otherwise, it will just be published to your web site.

So yes, from the user's perspective, one click can indeed translate a page in multiple languages, and publish it to multiple web sites. Our company is doing this, only we are doing our own in-house translation.

Answer (score -1):

I have not used this, but I looked into it awhile ago and this looks to be the best solutions I have seen.

http://umbraco.org/blog/2009/3/25/microsoft-translator-and-umbraco

Comment: "Microsoft translator is a Machine translation webservice" the question is asking for a solution for translations already "human generated."

Comment: "allows a user to click a button and convert all the text to another language" hmmm...

Answer (score -3):

That is not how major businesses do translation. It's good for quick and dirty, general idea translation, but it's not for anyone serious about messaging to multiple languages and cultures. Typically, businesses work with translation vendors and grow translation memories that help to guide content authors to creating a consistent message and to reuse content (keeping translation costs down).

This is a big subject, not a small one. Honestly, I'm kind of flabbergasted at how to answer this question, so I'll stop here.

Comment: I'm not sure you read the question correctly... he stated that it WOULD be human generated, not "click a button to run through google translate."

Comment: I thought I did, and based on the fact that others answered the question the same way, I'm not alone in that. (Maybe the question was edited later..?)

All I was saying is this: Translation is a complex business process that goes far beyond 'show text, have someone edit text, submit new text'. 

Whether or not you click a button and have it machine translated or human translated, there's a lot more that goes into this process such as working with translation memories, fuzzy matching, variables, entities, includes, and reusable content.

Comment: As JustEngland has noted Tridion is a serious player in this area. But let's give its full title: "SDL Tridion". These days Tridion is part of the SDL group, and in addition to being a powerful, enterprise web CMS, it also has direct integrations with the SDL translation management software. (Not machine translation, but software-supported human translation.)